# Get All nodes in relationship and all not in

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm actually trying to do a request like that.
I want :

- All Geo points.

  - From them (Geo) i want all their network systems (NS).

    - From them (NS) i want all their machine.

      - From them (Machines) i want all their VLAN.
    - From them (NS) i want all their network systems.
    - From them (NS) i want all their network systems BUT which havent a machine.

My nodes :

- Geo
- NS
- Machine
- VLAN

My Relationships :

- GeoNS
- MachNS
- NSNS
- VLANMach

For now i have this query :

```
MATCH (a:Geo)-[b:GeoNS]-(c:NS)
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[d:MachNS]-(e:Machine)-[f:VLANMach]-(g:VLAN)
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[h:NSNS]-(i:NS)
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[p:NSNS]-(q:NS)
return a
```

But as you can see, the last optional match is based on NS which have a machine.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last `OPTIONAL MATCH` can use a `WHERE` clause to filter out `q` nodes that have a `MachNS` relationship:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[p:NSNS]-(q:NS)
WHERE NOT (q)-[:MachNS]-()
```

*By the way, your `RETURN` clause is not valid, since the query does not define an `s` variable. Also, the query should be returning the results of all your matches.*

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah it's normal for the s variable i'll put something else on the request later. Gonna try what you said